# Generate filename with creation date

Tags: php, datetime, filenames, dompdf

I'm using dompdf to create and mail a PDF file to my mail and at the same time, save a .txt version on the server.
Saving the file is working as it should, but im having a bit of trouble getting it to save it with a unique name. In this case i wanted something like date-time.txt ( 06-09-2012_11:43.txt )

or even better, if it could have the name from the text field "refnr" as the name.

```
<label for="refnr"><b>Referensnummer:</b></label>
<input type="text" name="refnr" id="refnr" class="input" />
```

The code looks like this:

```
$html = '/html.php';
$filename = $dir.'/Admin/files/"date here".txt';
$dompdf = new DOMPDF(); 
$dompdf->load_html($html); 
$dompdf->set_paper('a4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render(); 
file_put_contents($filename, $dompdf->output());
```

I tried to play around with `$name='myfile_'.date('m-d-Y_hia)';` but couldn't make that work, it just gave an error on that line every time.
So now im here to seek the guidance from you smart people :)

Comment: "It just gave an error" -> which?

Comment: it just said Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /var/www/virtual/denully.dk/try-it.dk/htdocs/Ikea/form.php on line 34  :) not that helpful i think hehe,  line 34 was the $filename = $dir.'/Admin/files/"date here".txt'; line

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You put the `)` before you closed the string format code:

```
$name='myfile_'.date('m-d-Y_hia');
```

Should work fine.

As Jan1337z points out, you probably *want* a suffix on the file:

```
$name='myfile_'.date('m-d-Y_hia').'.txt';
```

Not having a suffix should't stop the file being created - but having it will probably help make it easily usable.

Comment: Ah always a little ' making all the problems hehe,  Thanks alot to both of you :)